# Applying translate() to a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, translate, textblob

I have a pandas dataframe with tweets in portuguese. I want to translate them in a new column of the dataframe using textblob.

```
df_pt['Traduccion'] = df_pt['text'].apply(TextBlob.translate(from_lang="pt",to='en'))
```

This is the error I get:

> TypeError: translate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

This is a sample of what I have in df_pt['text']:

> Acabou de publicar uma foto em Penha Circular, Rio De Janeiro, Brazil

Comment: I also realized that the type of df_pt['text'] is incorrect but I dont know how to take care of it either

Comment: Provide `df_pt['text']` sample.

Comment: If I do type, I get pandas.core.series.Series

Answer (score 2):

translate() require instantiation before use.

Try this:

```
df['Traduccion'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x).translate(from_lang="pt", to='en')).astype('str')
```

Comment: returned this: HTTPError: Service Unavailable. Maybe the error is that some tweets contain urls and emojis?

Comment: In that case, I suggest you write another function to handle exceptions instead.